# How can we use spring-data-jpa-datatables spring-data-envers together in one project

Tags: datatables, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-envers

I have this enabled in my database config. Which enabled to fetch Audit logs with the help of JPA methods. (spring-data-envers) is being used in POM for this

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

Now I want to use jquery datatable's back-end processing. For this I will be using (spring-data-jpa-datatables) in my POM.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

How can I use both of them in one Single Project.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean` seems to be rather simple. 
It performs a simple check and then does it's own thing or invokes `super`, i.e. `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean`

By reimplementing that but inheriting from `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean` instead you should be able to use both in one project.